# How to bind and query LDAP server without specifying user credentials

Tags: macos, active-directory, ldap, macos-sierra

Currently my Mac has been successfully configured to be in Active Directory Domain. (System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Options -> Network Account Server)

We are developing a Mac application that has following requirements:

1. It should communicate with the LDAP server in Active Directory Domain and retrieve users & their attributes from LDAP server.
2. While communicating (bind or search) with the LDAP server, we are not allowed to explicitly specify logged-in user's credentials. (e.g. we should not prompt username / password screen to the user)

If we **explicitly specify** logged-in user's credentials,

•   we are able to bind to the LDAP server

•   we are able to search the users & their attributes in LDAP server.

If we **do not specify** logged-in user's credentials,

•   we are able to bind to the LDAP server

•   but it does not allow us to search the users & their attributes in LDAP server.

We are currently using OpenLDAP framework for LDAP operations.

Is there a way with which we can use logged-in user's credentials implicitly while communicating with the LDAP server?

Can you please guide us how we can query LDAP server (search users & their attributes in LDAP server) without specifying logged-in user's credentials explicitly.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need an admin login for your application.

Comment: By default, you cannot search users and their attributes in Active Directory LDAP unless you specify credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way with which we can use logged-in user's credentials
>   implicitly while communicating with the LDAP server?

Maybe.

IF you CAN set up  [Kerberos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206878) (and [SPNEGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) is using a WEB browser) you might be able to obtain a "ticket" that you could then use a [GSSAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) to Authenticate the user.

You would probably be more secure if you used a one of the many third-party [Access Manager Products](https://www.google.com/search?q=Access%20Manager%20Products&oq=Access%20Manager%20Products) to perform these services due to the inherent security risks involved.